# Why does Backbone comparator not compare two objects?

Tags: backbone.js

In Ruby and Java you compare one object to another and return a number based on the order of those two objects. [Backbone has support](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator) for sorting based solely on a single object.

This seems counter-initiative and more complex.  Why does Backbone do this?  Is there an advantage of using this technique?

Comment: Would you mind clarifying what you mean by "based solely on a single object". I get the impression you are referring to the comparator mechanism in Backbone but cannot be sure from context alone.

Comment: if you create a comparator function that takes a single argument, you write it such that it returns a value that can be compared with standard comparison operators `<` and `>`

Comment: The form that returns a single value is simpler to use in some cases. For example, if you wanted to sort on a numeric ID then you just return that, instead of writing a full comparison function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [the docs](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-comparator):

> Comparator function can be defined as either a sortBy (pass a function that takes a single argument), or as a sort (pass a comparator function that expects two arguments).

This means that you can implement the `Comparator` in the classic way :  a function with 2 parameters that behaves like the native javascript `sort` function for arrays.
Backbone just adds another way of sorting your collections that's borrowed from [underscore](http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy).

Comment: I just saw this, but it doesn't really answer the question of why do it the other way.  I guess it has to do with performance, but I am looking for some kind of confirmation.

Comment: It's not about performance, it's just an option. Moreover I think `sort` should work faster since it's native array function.

Comment: @Sam I think this answers your question, it is telling you that your preconception of _"Backbone has support for sorting based **solely** on a single object"_ was wrong.

Comment: Adding to the above response, according to the current docs, there is a third option for comparator: it can be "... a string indicating the attribute to sort by".